# float division error in python with variables

Tags: python, error-handling, floating-point, division

so I'm doing something really simple:

```
shared = sum*2.0/(totalCNV(CNVs1,str(chrom))+totalCNV(CNVs2,str(chrom)))
```

and I get this:

```
ZeroDivisionError: float division
```

So now I just want to make it a floating point division, but I don't know how to do that. Can I just convert all the variables to floating points? Any suggestions? Cheers!

Comment: You already do floating point division. The error tells that you are dividing by `0`.

Comment: you can use float(integer) to convert to float, but It will not help you in case you do division by zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting implies that

```
(totalCNV(CNVs1,str(chrom))+totalCNV(CNVs2,str(chrom)))
```

is evaluating to zero, so when you try to do a division with that as the denominator, you're dividing by zero.

If that error is unexpected, chances are there's a problem earlier in your code.